# How can I get the last row of every stage of every job?

Tags: mysql

I've been taking too long trying to solve this, I need to filter this table:

```
+----+-------+-------+
| id | jobID |stageID|
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 |     1 |     1 |
|  2 |     1 |     2 |
|  3 |     1 |     2 |
|  4 |     1 |     1 |
|  5 |     2 |     2 |
|  6 |     2 |     1 |
|  7 |     2 |     1 |
|  8 |     2 |     2 |
+----+-------+-------+
```

You see every job has many rows with different stages, I need to get the last row of every stage of every job.

For example, look at job 1. It has 4 rows, each one with a given stage. I'd need to get the last entry of a stage for that job, which means, rows 3 and 4.

So for the full table I need to get rows No. 3, 4, 7 and 8, like this

```
+----+-------+-------+
| id | jobID |stageID|
+----+-------+-------+
|  3 |     1 |     2 |
|  4 |     1 |     1 |
|  7 |     2 |     1 |
|  8 |     2 |     2 |
+----+-------+-------+
```

I think I'll go nuts. I try with `GROUP_BY` but it groups the stages without taking in count the jobs.
Can you help me?

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: It shows 5.7.12

Answer (score 0):

This is simply:

```
select max(id) as id, jobID, stageID
from yourtable
group by jobID, stageID
```

If you need additional information selected, use that as a subselect:

```
select yourtable.id, yourtable.jobID, yourtable.stageID, yourtable.other
from (
    select max(id) as id
    from yourtable
    group by jobID, stageID
) max_job_stage_ids
join yourtable using (id)
```

or use `IN` (I find this less helpful in visualizing the query plan, but some people prefer it):

```
select id, jobID, stageID, other
from yourtable
where id in (select max(id) from yourtable group by jobID, stageID)
```